# How to call a speech praising a laureate of a prize?

Tags: vocabulary

I will take part in an event during which several prizes will be handed.  There will be a short speech about each winner, explaining what he got the prize for.  What do you call this speech in English?  I found three candidates:

- eulogy
- laudation
- citation

Which are correct?  Which are the best?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably describing an *introductory speech* where you introduce the winner. None of your other choices fit really. As far as I can tell from searching around, the term *laudatory speech* is actually [quite common](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&biw=1440&bih=710&q=%22laudatory+speech%22&oq=%22laudatory+speech%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i30l6j0l2j0i30j0i8i30.919.1610.0.1792.2.2.0.0.0.0.113.225.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.53.serp..0.2.223.y_me1D4jqMI) and is probably your best choice.

1. [A eulogy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eulogy). That would be fine if the person who won the award is dead. Not so fine otherwise. While the word is not restricted to praising the dead, that's what it is most often used for.
2. [A laudation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/laudation?s=t). While this word does indeed fit, it is not very common, most people would have no idea what you're talking about and it is really very strong. To *laud* someone is to shower them with praise. Most importantly, it does not describe a speech, it is simply the act of praising someone highly. Note that, as mentioned above, *laudatory speech* is fine. It is the use of the noun *a laudation* that is tricky.
3. [A citation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/citation?s=t). This one doesn't fit at all. It is not a speech but a simple mention. Presumably, what confused you was uses like *a citation for bravery*. That, however, is not praise and certainly not a speech, it just means that the soldier in question got a mark next to their name. They got a "mention".

Comment: When the Fields medals are presented (the highest prize in mathematics), there is always a [*"laudation"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=fields+medal+laudations&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) talk that explains the work the winners are being recognized for. I very much doubt that the Fields Medals are unique in this respect, so I think *laudation* is clearly the best choice of the three options the OP gave. It's much better than *introductory speech*, which sounds like a brief 2-minute introduction before the prize winner gives a speech.

Comment: @PeterShor I think you mean _laudatory speech_ which I hadn't considered and makes much more sense. It's the _laudation_ I have issues with. I will include _laudatory_ in my answer.

Comment: The Fields Medal laudatory speeches are actually called *"laudations"* (see the link in my previous comment), but I agree that *"laudatory speech"* is more comprehensible for the general public, and just as good.

Comment: @PeterShor I had no idea what they were called before reading your comment and searching for them. Ngrams gives no hits for _laudation speech_ but many for _laudatory speach_. On the other hand, the videos of the speeches themselves are indeed listed on youtube as _laudations_. I still dislike it but with less and less reason to :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **encomium**, defined by Google as a speech or piece of writing that praises someone or something highly.  It's not common, but it is generally understood. Out of your candidates, *eulogy* is too closely associated with funerals and memorials, and *laudation* is probably quite rare (at least, I've never heard it used).  *Citation* does have a definition that matches, but it doesn't sound right in the context to my ear --perhaps because the most dominant definition for *cite* is to reference the source of your quotes.

Answer (score 1):

A speech in praise of someone is a 'tribute'. Tribute speech; to pay tribute (to someone); a speech in tribute (to someone).